# Rstudio extremely slow. Projects on a shared drive, but its painfully slow

Tags: r, rstudio

I started a new remote job that requires me to use R, but the Rstudio is extremely slow. It has been two weeks and I want to get this sorted before my boss gets frustrated. I am not very well versed in R but can carry out basic analyses. Whenever I run a chunk in Rmarkdown it takes like 30 minutes to run. The projects are on a shared network drive, but my colleagues are not facing the same difficulty, and their run time is much much faster than mine.

```
.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/kbanipal/Microsoft" "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.4/library"

getwd()
[1] "Z:/Projects/Infectious Disease/2019 Novel Coronavirus (January 2020)/wec_cases/New Case Report"

Sys.info()
sysname release version nodename machine login user
"Windows" "10 x64" "build 19042" "M0076" "x86-64" "kbanipal" "kbanipal"
effective_user
"kbanipal"
```

I will greatly appreciate any help. Many thanks

Comment: What kind of code are you trying to run in RMarkdown that feels slow? Reading csvs or something from a shared drive could totally slow things down, but 30 min for a chunk seems ridiculous.

Comment: I am trying to run a project that is on a network drive. There is a lot of merging and functions applied to different csv files, but its very slow on my computer compared to my peers. When I open the project (screenshot attached), it takes a good while for all the panes to load.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't attach the screenshot in comments, but the panes first turn grey then I am able to execute a simple code like mutate() after 3 mins. It is really slowing me down. I believe something is wrong with my working directory or path maybe? The code I am trying to run is pretty complicated with a lot of functions (written by an ex- employee who was pretty good at R)

Comment: If I were you, I'd read in the CSVs you need in a separate chunk and cache them, and then do all the data wrangling. That way you're not re-reading the csvs every time you want to run the code, and it'll speed up a bunch with caching

Comment: This question does not seem to have all the information needed to fully understand the issue much less answer any questions. Matt is right to ask for code. How about some more detailed info on the data structure being read in?...